# Green's theorem application

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

**Problem**

Determine all circles $\mathcal C$ on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $$\int_{\mathcal C}-y^2dx+3xdy=6\pi$$

**My attempt at a solution**

If I call $P(x,y)=-y^2$ and $Q(x,y)=3x$, then I can apply Green's theorem to the region $D$ enclosed by the circle of radius $R$ centered at $(a,b)$. I'll use a change of variables to describe $D$ with the transformation $T(\theta,r)=(r\cos(\theta)+a,r\sin(\theta)+b)$. We have the identity $$\int_{\mathcal C} Pdx+Qdy=\iint_D (\dfrac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial y})dxdy$$

The double integral equals to $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^R((3+2(r\sin(\theta)+b)r)drd\theta$$$$=\int_0^{2\pi}((\dfrac{3+2b}{2})R^2+\dfrac{2R^3}{3}\sin(\theta))d\theta$$$$=(3+2b)R^2\pi$$

So, by the chain of equalities, we have $$\int_{\mathcal C}-y^2dx+3xdy=6\pi$$ if and only if $$=(3+2b)R^2\pi=6\pi$$

Notice that the condition isn't satisfied for any circle of arbitrary radius $R$ centered at $(a,b)$ with $b \leq \dfrac{-3}{2}$.

Now, if the circle is  centered at an arbitrary point $(a,b)$ with $b>\frac{-3}{2}$ then the radius must satisfy $R=\sqrt{\dfrac{6}{3+2b}}$.

I would appreciate if someone could take a look at my solution and let me know if there are any mistakes. Anybody who wants to add an alternative answer or comments that complement the computational aspect of the solution is welcome to share it.

Comment: You seem to be using the word "circumference" in a non-standard way. I can make sense of your question by substituting "perimeter of a circle" for "circumference" -- is that what you mean?

Comment: Oh, I thought the word to describe that curve was "circumference", but the "perimeter of a circle" doesn't refer to a numerical quantity? Wouldn't "circle" or maybe "disk" be correct?

Comment: "perimeter" can mean both the curve along the edge of a shape and the length of that curve. (The double meaning can be seen in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perimeter), which accidentally equivocates between the two.) In everyday speech, "circumference" has the same double meaning, but it's rarely used for the curve itself in mathematics. You can certainly use "circle"; I think that would be more than clear enough; I just proposed "perimeter of a circle" because I thought you wanted to emphasize that you mean the boundary and not the interior of the circle.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the terminology up, I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: But now you've only changed the first instance and left everything else as "circumference" -- that actually makes it less rather than more clear. I think your suggestion of just writing "circle" was good; that would make it easier to read than having "perimeter of a circle" everywhere.